# Visual State Manageer Not Responding to Maximise/Minimize Button

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I'm playing around/learning visual state manager for UWP. I have a piece of code that does not respond to the triggers/setters when I hit the maximize/minimize button on the app. It responds fine if I manually resize the box though.

I have a second piece of code that responds tot he triggers/setters just fine when I hit the maximize/minimize button.

Both code look pretty identical to me but it seems I am missing something. Thank you in advance for your assistance

Here is the code that is not responding to the maximize/minimize button:

```
 <Grid Name="MyGrid" Background="White">

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Groups">
            <VisualState x:Name="WindowsPhone">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Inline"/>
                    <Setter Target="HamburgerButton.Width" Value="100"/>
                    <Setter Target="MyGrid.Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                    <Setter Target="AutoSuggestBox.Visibility" Value="Compact"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="WindowsTablet">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Overlay"/>
                    <Setter Target="AutoSuggestBox.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="MyGrid.Background" Value="HotPink"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Desktop">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800"/>                        
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>                  
                    <Setter Target="MyGrid.Background" Value="Orange"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>



    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <RelativePanel>
        <Button Name="HamburgerButton"
                Width="50"
                Height="50"
                Click="HamburgerButton_Click"
                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                Content="&#xE700;"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"/>

        <AutoSuggestBox Name="AutoSuggestBox"
                        QueryIcon="Find"
                        PlaceholderText="Search"
                        Width="200"                                  
                        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                        Margin="0,10,0,0"/>


    </RelativePanel>

    <SplitView Grid.Row="1"
               Name="MySplitView"
               IsPaneOpen="False"
               CompactPaneLength="50"
               OpenPaneLength="200"
               DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">


        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox Name="MylistBox"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     SelectionChanged="MylistBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Name="FirstIcon"
                                   FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                   FontSize="30"
                                   Text="&#xE80F;"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="TextTextBlock"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   Text="Hello"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Name="SecondIcon"
                                   FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                   FontSize="30"
                                   Text="&#xE80F;"/>

                        <TextBlock Name="SeconTextBlock"
                                   FontFamily="20"
                                   Text="Hello Again"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </SplitView.Pane>


    </SplitView>

</Grid>
```

And this is the code that works fine:

```
 <Grid Name="ColorGrid" Background="Pink">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStatePhone">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                 <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ColorGrid.Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Target="MessageTextBlock.FontSize" Value="18"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateTablet">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ColorGrid.Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    <Setter Target="MessageTextBlock.FontSize" Value="40"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateDesktop">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ColorGrid.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Setter Target="MessageTextBlock.FontSize" Value="60"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <TextBlock Name="MessageTextBlock" Text="Hello I am forgetting something"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce this in a blank project on 14393. The weird thing about this is that this only seems to happen in a debugging session. If you run without debugging, or launch from Start, everything works correctly.

Comment: @BoltClock hmmm. weird indeed. I tested as you mentioned without debugging or from start and it works correctly. 

What a strange little bug

Answer (score 0):

@BoltClock What's even stranger is I created another project and this one responds fine to the maximize and minimize button but when I resize it manually, it does not respond to the "Tablet" state.

If I launch from the start screen though, everything works fine.

`

```
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <RelativePanel>
        <Button Name="HamburgerButton"
            Height="50"
            Width="50"
            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
            Content="&#xE700;"
            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
            Click="HamburgerButton_Click_1"/>

        <AutoSuggestBox Name="AutoSuggest"
                        Width="200"
                        QueryIcon="Find"
                        PlaceholderText="Search"
                        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                        Margin="0,10,0,0"
                        />

        <TextBlock Name="TitleTextBlock"
                   FontSize="30"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   RelativePanel.RightOf="HamburgerButton"
                   Text="Home"/>
    </RelativePanel>


    <SplitView Name="MySplitView"
               Grid.Row="1"
               OpenPaneLength="200"
               CompactPaneLength="50"
               DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox SelectionMode="Single"
                     SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"
                    >
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Name="FirstIcon"
                                   FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                   FontSize="30"
                                   Text="&#xE80F;"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="FirstText"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   Text="Hello"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Name="SecondIcon"
                               FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                               FontSize="30"
                               Text="&#xE80F;"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="SecondText"
                               FontSize="20"
                               Text="Hello Again"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Margin="10,0,0,0"/>

                </StackPanel>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock/>
                        <TextBlock/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>

            </ListBox>
        </SplitView.Pane>

    </SplitView>

</Grid>`
```